# Inherited SVG functional component cannot add style styled-components

Tags: svg

I want to add animation effect to SVG in styled components, but it doesn't work. Please help me. Thank you

```
const LoadIconComponent = ({ color }: { color?: string }) => (
  <svg ... >
    <path
      d='...'
      p-id='2419'
      fill={color || "#FFFFFF"}
    ></path>
  </svg>
);


const animate = `
    0%{transform: rotate(0deg)};
    100%{transform: rotate(360deg)}
`;

const keyframe = keyframes`${animate}`;

const LoadIcon = styled(LoadIconComponent)`
  animation: ${keyframe} 1s linear;
  background-color: red;
`;
```

[image]

This is OK. Is there a good way

```
const LoadIcon = styled.svg.attrs({
  children: (
    <path
      d='...'
      p-id='2419'
      fill='#FFFFFF'
    ></path>
  ),
  viewBox: "0 0 1024 1024",
  version: "1.1",
  xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
  "p-id": "2418",
  width: "1rem",
  height: "1rem",
})`
  animation: ${keyframe} 1s linear infinite;
`;
```